# Restrict user role Author from viewing comments in admin interface

Tags: author, comments, authorization

I want to add an user as an Author to my blog, so that he can publish posts. But i don't want him to be able to view all the (unapproved) comments in the *admin interface*.

Is there any code snippet / plugin that can do what i want ?

I tried plugins like *Role Scoper* and *Members*. Role Scoper is too complicated i don't even know where to start. Members can only edit the basic wordpress access for roles.

Answer (score 1):

For a user to be able to see the list of other users in wp-admin, he or she needs the [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)  list_users, to be able to edit existing profiles, he or she needs edit_users, to add new ones add_users and to delete old ones delete_users.

For managing a site with multiple specific user roles that need to have certain capabilities and not to have others, I highly recommend using a mixture of two plugins:

[Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) gives you control over what part of the admin interface is shown to what role

[Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) lets you edit the capabilities of a specific role and add new roles as needed

Comment: Erm, _Adminimize_ only does a part of what I aim to do. When I log in as an authors, it _hides_ the comment section in the admin interface, but _does not_ do the authorization part, i.e. restricting me from actually viewing the comments. I can get to the comments by clicking on "View all comments" in the dashboard, or by typing manually `/wp-admin/edit-comments.php` into browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [Capability Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/) plugin, which is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same answer, and then elsewhere came across the [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) -- it does exactly what the OP requested (and what I was looking for).

Answer (score -3):

you can go to wp-admin folder -> menu.php and look for something like this

$menu[25] = array( sprintf( __('Comments %s')....

then add this condition around this line

global $current_user;
    if($current_user->user_level==10){the line should be here}

this way no one can see the comments except the admin.

Comment: Modifying core WP files is always a bad idea. Core files should be left unaltered in order to avoid functionality loss upon WP ugrades.

Comment: thank you for this important info. i'll try to be away from that . but i still have this problem , the author can see all comments but he can edit only his comments .. no need to show him other comments ! your plugin is very nice but it doesn't help me with that  ... thank you